# Is leiden algorithm is applied on a dataframe which is undirected

Tags: python, graph, networkx, cluster-computing

I constructed a graph and wanted to know how can we apply the Leiden algorithm. I have started using the Louvain algorithm but it's taking a lot of time. I am new to community detection and came to know that Leiden works very fast when compared to Louvain. Can anyone help me with how can I implement the Leiden algorithm?

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_new, 'Source', 'Target',['WeightCount', 'weight_cosine'], nx.Graph())
```

This is the graph I have constructed. I wanted to know whether I can implement the Leiden algorithm or not. I have implemented the following code but I am facing an error which is beginner step.

```
partition = la.find_partition(G, la.ModularityVertexPartition)
```

the error is

```
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'vcount'
```

Let me know whether my initial graph is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have constructed a graph using `networkx`. The `leidenalg` package works with `igraph`, not with `networkx`. You can easily first convert the graph to an `igraph` graph using [`ig.Graph.from_networkx`](https://igraph.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.2/api/igraph.Graph.html#from_networkx) (after installing `igraph` and doing `import igraph as ig`).